# How is () => {...} different from () =>

Tags: javascript

I've found a weird issue.

given a filter and an array of objects, I would like to select only those objects that match the filter.

Weirdly, this doesn't work

```
this.state.articles.filter((article) => {
  article.category === filter 
})
```

while this does

```
this.state.articles.filter((article) => article.category === filter )
```

I originally thought they would evaluate the same, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Any ideas why?

Comment: The first one uses a block of code, so a return statement is needed. The second one uses the implicit return of an arrow function

Comment: `(article) => article.category === filter )` is `(article) => { return article.category === filter })`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_arrow_function_expression_(%3E)

Comment: How did this get so many upvotes? Just curious--it's in the language spec, it's documented on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: @DaveNewton it's difficult to find the right information, and at times it's easier just to have a conversation about certain problems people face. I guess people like to talk, even if it's on a staticish forum like SO.

Comment: @mark If SO was a cafe or office water cooler, great. It's not, and has a clear mandate to reduce duplicates, reduce noise, and encourage research.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you open a block `{}` in an arrow function, the `return` isn't implied anymore.

You have to write it down :

```
this.state.articles.filter((article) => {
  return article.category === filter 
})
```

Comment: "implicit return" is the term if anyone wants to Google it.

Comment: This is equivalent to `function(article){ [...] }`, in ES5 and older, while `(article) => article.category === filter` is equivalent to `function(article){ return [...] }`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No, they are not equivalent.

Comment: Then what would be the equivalent for those?

Answer (score 8):

Javascript ES6 arrow functions work in a particular manner which can best be described via an example:

```js
let multiply1 = (number) => number * 2;
// When we are returning one value we can put this expression on the same line

// this is the same as:
let multiply2 = (number) => { return number * 2};

//when we have 1 argument we can omit the parentheses
let multiply3 = number => number * 2;


// When we want to write multiple line we have to put brackets like this:
let multiply4 = (number) => { 
console.log('inside arrow function');
return number * 2;
};

console.log(multiply1(2));
console.log(multiply2(2));
console.log(multiply3(2));
console.log(multiply4(2));
```

When the arrow function is returning an expression it is very convenient to not have to explicitly write the `return` statement and the square brackets `{}`. This allows for more concise code.

Answer (score 5):

> How is () => {…} different from () =>

```
+----+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| #  | Using curly brace              | Without curly brace                   |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1. | Needs explicit return          | Returns the statement implicitly      |
| 2. | `undefined` if no return used  | Returns the value of expression       |
| 3. | return {} // ok                | {} // buggy, ({}) // ok               |
| 4. | Useful for multi-line code     | Useful for single line code           |
| 5. | Okay even for single line      | Buggy for multi line                  |
+----+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Here's the examples for above differences:

Example: 1

```
// Needs explicit return
() => {
  return value
}
// Returns the value
() => value
```

Example: 2

```
// Returns undefined
() => {
  1 == true
}
// Returns true
() => 1 == true // returns true
```

Example: 3

```
// ok, returns {key: value}
() => {
  return {key: value}
}
// Wrap with () to return an object
() => {key: value} // buggy
() => ({key: value}) // ok
```

Example: 4

```
// Useful for multi-line code
() => {
  const a = 1
  const b = 2
  return a * b
}
// Useful for single line code
() => 1 * 2
```

Example: 5

```
// Okay even for single line code
() => { return 1 }
// Buggy for multi-line code
() => const a = 123; const b = 456; a + b; // buggy
() => 
     const a = 123
     const b = 456
     a + b // still buggy
```

---

When using filter function, [return statement is required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Return_value) to pass the test:

> A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned.

So, with the form `() =>`, you're implicitly returning the value, it will pass the test and works fine. But when you use `() => {...}`, you're not explicitly returning the statement, and won't work as you expect. It just returns an empty object.

So, to make your code work as expected, you should use the return statement:

```
this.state.articles.filter((article) => {
  return article.category === filter 
})
```

---

**PS**: I'm using the implicit and explicit word, what's exactly that in terms of JavaScript?

Implicit means JavaScript engine does it for us. Explicit means We need to do what we want. We can think similar in any terms.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that when you use `() => x`, it really means `() => { return x }`, so just how the statement `article.category === filter` on its own dosen't do anything, `{ article.category === filter }` dosen't explicitly return anything.