# How to watch multiple properties in Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to update a Vue component property, `station`, when one of several other properties are updated. It wouldn't work as a computed property because computed properties are synchronous and this requires an API request.

Based on an [issue reply in Vue core](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/844#issuecomment-335026928) I found the docs on [`vm.$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch). This looks to be what I need, but I can't figure out how it should be implemented in the context of this component context.

I think I should be using `this` in place of `vm` in the docs, but I'm not sure about that. Then again, using `this` on the left side of the arrow function that's the first parameter of `$watch` throws errors like `Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters`.

My use of `vm.$watch` is toward the end of the following component code. The error I keep getting is: `Failed watching path: "[object Object]" Watcher only accepts simple dot-delimited paths. For full control, use a function instead.` (I thought I was...)

```
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    {{ station }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ApiService from '@/services/ApiService';

export default {
  name: 'Chart',
  props: {
    mode: String,
    toDate: String,
    toTime: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      stationId: 3069,
      station: {}
    };
  },
  watch: {
    station: function() {
      // Render function
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getInfo: async function(opts) {
      const stationData = await ApiService[this.mode]({
        id: opts.id,
        toTime: `${opts.toDate}T${opts.toTime}`,
        fromTime: `${opts.fromDate}T${opts.fromTime}`
      })
        .then(res => {
          return res.data.station.properties;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
          return {};
        });

      return stationData;
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    // MY WATCHING STARTS HERE  
    this.$watch(
      () => return {
        mode: this.mode,
        stationId: this.stationId,
        toDate: this.toDate,
        toTime: this.toTime
      },
      async function(data) {
        this.station = await this.getInfo({
          mode: data.mode,
          id: data.stationId,
          toDate: data.toDate,
          toTime: data.toTime
        }).then(res => {
          return res;
        });
      }
    );
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your watcher is returning in arrow function. It should be like:

```
this.$watch(
  () => {
     return {
       mode: this.mode,
       stationId: this.stationId,
       toDate: this.toDate,
       toTime: this.toTime
     }
  },
```

This code is invalid use:

```
() => return {
```

Arrow function implicitly returns the value if no curly brace is used. So, you may also use like:

```
this.$watch(
  () => ({
     mode: this.mode,
     stationId: this.stationId,
     toDate: this.toDate,
     toTime: this.toTime
  }),
```

Notice, parentheses used for returning an object. You may also like to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334319/how-is-different-from/52334964#52334964) further.

Comment: Of course it was something silly like that. Thank you!