# Attempted import error: does not contain a default export

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm defining react component to connect with redux . I have the app and list components

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
  //import Login from './components/Login';
 import List from './components/List';
 import './App.css';
  class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (  <List />); } }
  export default App;
```

**List.js**

```js
  import React from 'react';
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';

  const mapStateToProps=  state =>{
     return { articles :state.articles};
      }
   const connectedList = ({ articles }) =>(
        {articles.map(e=>(      //////**1) here I get red under the dot(.) ie., error**
           <li key={e.id}>{e.title}</li>
         ))}
     );
   const List= connect(mapStateToProps)(connectedList);
   export default List;
```

why do **1) here I get red under the dot(.) ie., error**

I have exported List but I'm thrown this error

Attempted import error: './components/List' does not contain a default export (imported as 'List').

Actually I'm newbie to redux so Please explain lemme know where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove curly brace:

```js
const connectedList = ({ articles }) =>(
   articles.map(e=>( // implicit return
      <li key={e.id}>{e.title}</li>
   )
));
```

Or, using curly brace:

```js
const connectedList = ({ articles }) => { // no parentheses
   return articles.map(e=>( // explicitly use return
      <li key={e.id}>{e.title}</li>
   )
});
```

Using curly brace in parentheses indicates that you're returning an object. But articles.map... is obviously not an object rather looping through an object.

Comment: what's the implicit and explicit return please explain?

Comment: @Tested your function should be const connectedList = ({ articles }) =>{ but not const connectedList = ({ articles }) =>(        Hope you will find the mistake you did

Comment: @Tested See [my another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334319/how-is-different-from/52334964#52334964) for further help.