# State is null initially after using get request in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, get, axios

I have a react component where I want to get some data, using componentDidmount to get the data initially:

```
componentDidMount(){
axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50').then( response =>{
for(var key in response.data.results){

    const question = [...this.state.question, response.data.results[key].question];
    const answer = [...this.state.answer, response.data.results[key].correct_answer];
    const wrongAnswers = [...this.state.wrongAnswers, response.data.results[key].incorrect_answers];
    this.setState( prevState => ({
        question: question,
        answer: answer,
        wrongAnswers: wrongAnswers
 }));    
 }
  });
 }
```

the problem is that I can't map the answers of wrongAnswers because they are undefined initially

```
  const {wrongAnswers} = this.state;
 {wrongAnswers[this.state.random] && this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random].map((wrongAnswer, index) => { //this does not display 
<p key={'Key-'+index}>here it is= {wrongAnswer}</p>
  })}
```

I tried making some checks to see when gets rendered what

```
 {this.state.wrongAnswers &&
console.log('the state is ' +this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random]);
} //this renders undefined initially, then renders an array of the right answers..
```

what is strange is that, if I just display the state, without performing any operations, it is displayed correctly.

```
  <p>{this.state.question[this.state.random]}</p> // displays the state correctly

  <p>{this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random]}</p> //displays the state correctly
```

I suspect, that I can't perform any operations, because it is not loaded initially, but since I put it in componentDidMount, you would suspect, that this problem would not occur?

EDIT:

whenever i put in the conditions for a simply parapragh

```
{this.state.random !== undefined && this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random] !== undefined &&

    <p> condition is met </p>

  }
```

it prints out

but when i map the array:

```
  {this.state.random !== undefined && this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random] !== undefined && this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random].map((wrongAnswer, index) => {
      console.log('inside the right method!'); //logs correctly three times like intended but does not print any jsx
    <p key={'Key-'+index}>here it is= {wrongAnswer}</p>

  })}
```

nothing is printed out.

Comment: `componentDidMount` will initiate the request and lifecycle will continue on to render before request has completed

Comment: But how can i make so it displays after it get the data, the condition met, will always be false, no matter how many times the UI re renders?

Comment: By only rendering once those arrays have length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that `<p>{this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random]}</p>` works when placed inside the render hook. It means you will always get `wrongAnswers` ie. not `undefined` and invoking on `wrongAnswers` array of the state, there will be no error at initial render and it gets correct result at next render.

But using this code in componentDidMount hook,

```
{
  this.state.wrongAnswers &&
  console.log(this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random]);
}
```

At first time, it will obviously get the `undefined` because at that time `this.state.random` might be `undefined` or `null` and due to this reason, you will get `undefined`. For example:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3]
console.log(arr[undefined]) // undefined
console.log(arr[null]) // undefined
```

Thus, I would suggest you to check the `random` state first and then use `wrongAnswers` with it:

```
{
  this.state.random &&
  console.log(this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random]);
}
```

The following will be unnecessary as `wrongAnswers` are not `undefined` at initial state as you stated. If you have not set `wrongAnswers` at initial state, then only the following is a way to do so:

```
{
  this.state.wrongAnswers &&
  this.state.random &&
  console.log(this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random]);
}
```

---

Sorry, I didn't figured out before your edit. But you need to use return statement while inside the map since you're using curly brace:

```
return <p>...</p>
```

You may also be interested to look [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334319/how-is-different-from/52334964#52334964) for further help, to know when to use return and when not to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer the issue is that even if i make both conditions, it does no render anything

Comment: {this.state.random && this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random].map((wrongAnswer, index) => {
          console.log('inside the right method!');
    <p key={'Key-'+index}>here it is= {wrongAnswer}</p>
      })}

Comment: You'll also need  to assure `this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random]` is not `undefined` before using map.

Comment: I tried this, and the conditions are when i just display a simple paragraph, but i won't work when i map the array (i will edit the question)