# ReactJS and setState syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to understand the below syntax in my React app. Essentially I wanted to understand the code inside setState()

```
this.getSomePromise().then(
      // resolve callback function
      someImg =>
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          doggo: someImg.message
        })),
      // reject callback function
      () => alert("Rejected!")
    );
```

What I was expecting was a syntax like this;

```
    this.setState(prevState => {
// some code
    })
```

But the round bracket immediately after `prevState =>` is getting me confused.

Comment: `const foo = () => {}` with `foo() // returns undefined`, instead `const bar = () => ({})` with `bar() // return an empty object {}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is () => {...} different from () =>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334319/how-is-different-from) and [When should I use `return` in es6 Arrow Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450)

Comment: @adiga you should use a return in arrow functions when you have more business logic that you need to evaluate. If all your doing is immediately returning something then you can use the shorthand return method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 arrows use implicit return syntax that allows to skip `return` keyword. This is implicitly returned object:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  doggo: someImg.message
}))
```

Which is a shortcut for explicit return:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
 return {
  ...prevState,
  doggo: someImg.message
 }
})
```

This is object literal that is returned as new state:

```
{
  ...prevState,
  doggo: someImg.message
}
```

Not wrapping it with `(...)` parentheses would result in syntax error because `{...}` curly braces in object literal would be parsed as function brackets.

Comment: Thanks a lot...That really helps...Just a quick question...What does ...prevState represent ? Does it represent the ES6 REST/Spread operator syntax ?

Comment: This is ES2018 object spread, makes a shallow copy of `prevState` object. It's syntax sugar for `Object.assign({}, prevState)`