# array mapping not returning value react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function

```
  churnModel = () => {
        if (this.props.churnModel === undefined || this.props.churnModel.length === 0) {
          return("N/A")
        } else {
          this.props.churnModel.map((churn) => {
            if (churn === undefined || churn.length === 0) {
              return("N/A")
            } else {
              return(churn.map((model) => {
                this.service(model.scoreModelId)
              }))
            }
          })
        }
  };
```

The this.service functions looks like this...

```
service(e) {
  switch(e.toString().toLowerCase()) {
    case "in":
      return <span>in</span>
    case "rpt_callr":
      return <span>repeat</span>
    default:
      return <span>na</span>
  }
}
```

I am expecting to display the result in here:

```
<div className="riskScore">{this.churnModel()}</div>
```

Nothing gets displayed, but when I put in logs, those get printed.

What is happening here?

Comment: You missed the return statement inside map. It should be return this.service(model.scoreModelId)

Comment: doesnt matter... still doesnt work.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kxn064w85v

Comment: Check this out, I created a working demo resolving your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put `return` before `this.props.churnModel.map`.`this.service(model.scoreModelId)`

1. A `function` will return `undefined` if nothing is nothing is returned.
2. `map()` takes a callback and changes each element of array to `return` value of the that callback. If you don't `return` anything all elements will be `undefined`

You can also get rid of `return` before  `this.service(model.scoreModelId)` by removing `{}`.Like this.

```
return(churn.map((model) => this.service(model.scoreModelId)))
```

Here is the code

```
churnModel = () => {
        if (this.props.churnModel === undefined || this.props.churnModel.length === 0) {
          return("N/A")
        } else {
          return this.props.churnModel.map((churn) => {
            if (churn === undefined || churn.length === 0) {
              return("N/A")
            } else {
              return(churn.map((model) => {
                return this.service(model.scoreModelId)
              }))
            }
          })
        }
  };
```

Comment: @soldfor see I have updated. Actually you are missing two `return` statements

Comment: the added return worked... why do I have to return this and that and that and even that? seems silly to "return" within a return.

Comment: So you can avoid adding return if you use a arrow function like `return(churn.map((model) => this.service(model.scoreModelId)))`. These all are function, if you wanna have a value to the upper scope you need to return the value. I a way you are saying when I call you return me `something`.

Comment: @soldfor I have added explanation why you need `return`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `return` statement in couple of lines:

```
 churnModel = () => {
            if (this.props.churnModel === undefined || this.props.churnModel.length === 0) {
              return("N/A")
            } else {
              return this.props.churnModel.map((churn) => {
                if (churn === undefined || churn.length === 0) {
                  return("N/A")
                } else {
                  return(churn.map((model) => {
                    return this.service(model.scoreModelId)
                  }))
                }
              })
            }
      };
```

Why do you need return? It's because you're using [curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334319/how-is-different-from/52334964#52334964).

Comment: Whoa, I'm too late to answer just to give proper format to `return` statement with bold. Learnt how to add bold in formatted code anyways.