# map function doesn't work in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-map

I'm currently learning ReactJS and I can't spot what is wrong with my code. So, I have a function and map() method inside. I have written it in 2 ways(arrow and normal) but the normal function doesn't seem work(page reloads empty but no errors or code highlights shown). Just to clarify, I don't run these functions at the same time - one is being commented out while testing another one and then I switch it. Also, the arrow function works just fine.

Could you please check my code and advice what is the problem here?

// Arrow Function which works

```
function App() {
const appComponent = AppData.map((data) => <Data question={data.question} answer={data.answer} />);
return <div>{appComponent}</div>;
}
```

// Normal Function which doesn't work

```
function App() {
const appComponent = AppData.map(function (data) {
    <Data question={data.question} answer={data.answer} />
});
return <div>{appComponent}</div>;
}
```

Comment: The arrow notation written in a single like will automatically return the <Data....> but inside a normal function, you have to explicitly include the `return` statement which is missing in your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334319/how-is-different-from/52334964#52334964

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a return statement in your [`#Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback, currently your callback returns an array: `[undefined]`:

```
function App() {
  const appComponent = AppData.map(function (data) {
    return <Data question={data.question} answer={data.answer} />;
  });
  return <div>{appComponent}</div>;
}
```

See [examples in `#Array.map` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
let numbers = [1, 4, 9]
let roots = numbers.map(function(num) {
    return Math.sqrt(num)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning in the latter one.

```
function App() {
const appComponent = AppData.map(function (data) {
    return <Data question={data.question} answer={data.answer} />
});
return <div>{appComponent}</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that arrow functions implicitly return the value of their contained statement (unless they are wrapped with `{}` curly braces).

Here are the three ways to return values:

```js
() => 'returned';
() => { return 'returned'; };
function() { return 'returned'; };
```